# Some one please help with this script

Tags: sql-server

```
DELETE FROM Sql.dbo.Data DD
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT 
    TOP 100000 D.CLIENT, D.REFERENCE 
FROM Sql.dbo.Data D
INNER JOIN Sql.dbo.Log P
    ON D.CLIENT = P.CLIENT 
    AND D.REFERENCE = P.REF
WHERE P.RETENTION = 15 
) SS
ON DD.CLIENT = SS.CLIENT
AND DD.REFERENCE = SS.REFERENCE
```

Comment: What specifically do you need assistance with? What is it supposed to accomplish and what is it doing currently?

Comment: Not good at scripting. I want to delete data but getting syntax error

Comment: You are missing the table you want to delete: delete A  from TABLE_A A inner join TABLE_B B on A.column = B.column where CONDITIONS

Comment: For future reference - including the details of the problem, and the actual error message if you're getting one, go a long way to helping others help you. Glad you found your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this get you closer?

```
DELETE DD FROM Sql.dbo.Data DD
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT 
    TOP 100000 D.CLIENT, D.REFERENCE 
FROM Sql.dbo.Data D
INNER JOIN Sql.dbo.Log P
    ON D.CLIENT = P.CLIENT 
    AND D.REFERENCE = P.REF
WHERE P.RETENTION = 15 
) SS
ON DD.CLIENT = SS.CLIENT
AND DD.REFERENCE = SS.REFERENCE
```